# Force an application to open as split view in Windows 8+

Tags: windows, pdf, microsoft-metro

I have an application that allows the user to read different contents (pdf, images), in the local application, on Windows 8 and +.
But I need my application to stay open on the side while the user is looking at the content (so he can come back easily). I used LauncherOptions.DesiredRemainingView, which works well if the user is using Reader app (or equivalent) for reading PDFs. 
However, if he uses Adobe for example, it will not work, and my app will be hidden, while Adobe reader is displayed windowed on the desktop.

Is there a mean to either :
- force Adobe to open in split mode (using the DesiredRemainingView value)
- or, force the user to open the content with a given app (which would be Reader instead of Adobe) ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot force any size - the `Desired` prefix is intended to make it clear that this is something the app wants, but isn't guaranteed to be given.

You can try and get the PDF file to open in a specific reader app if you use the `LauncherOptions` -- in Windows 8.1, you can specify a preference for an app to install if the user doesn't currently have an app via [`PreferredApplicationPacakgeFamilyName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcheroptions.preferredapplicationpackagefamilyname.aspx). Starting in Windows 10 you can force a specific launch using [`TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcheroptions.targetapplicationpackagefamilyname.aspx).

Comment: `TargetApplicationPackageFamilyName` was what I was looking for (for the second solution). Unfortunately I have to make it work for Windows 8. But thanks !